# Oracle SQL Desktop DECODE function

Tags: sql, oracle11g, decode

I need to create a DECODE function that returns GOOD if a number is greater than 10 000 and BAD if it is less than 10 000. I know that I can use CASE, but my teacher wants us to do it with DECODE.

Comment: Get another teacher.  `DECODE()` is Oracle-specific syntax that has been replaced by the ANSI standard `CASE`.  `CASE` is also more powerful.

Comment: I wish I had better teachers. We are learning old programming...

Comment: SQL Desktop is not a common name... can  you give a link?

Comment: Compliments to your teacher for making you use everything oracle has to offer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem in "old" Oracle.  You can use the `sign()` function:

```
select decode(sign(number - 1000), 1, 'GOOD', -1, 'BAD', 0, 'EQUAL', 'Huh???')
```

`CASE` is much more sensible.

I am only answering because comments suggest that this is either really hard or impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what SQL Desktop is -- Google searches just return this page.

If you are talking about the Oracle function DECODE() and your question is asked correctly then the intent of your professor is to point out the answer to this problem is basically impossible to do and you really want to use a CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea of what you want to do.  You can adjust is for your assignment.

```
select records 
, decode ((records - 5), 0,  'five', 'ten') result
from (
select 5 records 
from dual
union 
select 10 records 
from dual
) x
```